Under what circumstances did Aziz Isa Elkun lose contact with his mother?
In his forward to Uyghur Poems, Aziz Isa Elkun (editor of the collection and translator of some of the poems) mentioned that he had lost contact with his mother in 2017, stating that his "greatest hope is that she is alive and well." Under what circumstances did this occur, and were they able to find each other again?

Aziz Isa Elkun fled China in 1999, and since 2001 has lived in exile in London due to his political activity. His father's health began to decline in 2016, and so Aziz applied for a visa on humanitarian grounds to return to China, but the application was rejected.
In November 2017 his father died. Aziz maintains a blog, although it is only updated sporadically, and he describes the events before and after his father's death in a posting entitled An Unanswered Telephone Call:

I haven’t spoken to my parents for several months, even though my
father is unwell, and I stopped calling my other relatives and friends
several years ago. It’s like this. A few months ago I called my
mother, and when she answered the phone she asked me not call her any
more, at least for while, because every time I called her from London,
about an hour later a group of policemen would come to their house.
The police told my mother not to answer her son’s calls. They said
there was an order from the regional police department that nobody
should take international telephone calls. The police told my mother
that if she didn’t obey this rule she would be punished...
I passed a long and anxious week after that call. On the following
Saturday I called my parents’ number, but there was no answer. Then I
tried my mum’s mobile, but the result was the same: no answer. I
listened to a Chinese language Red Song coming from her mobile for a
while, then the mobile signal slowly died away. It was pretty clear:
my mother was obeying orders and had left my call deliberately
unanswered.

At least until 2021, the most recent news I could find on his blog, the situation remains unchanged, and Aziz remains completely cut-off from his family, unable to visit China, and his mother unable to answer the telephone. His closest contact was that he was able to locate his father's grave on Google Earth - until the Chinese authorities bulldozed the area as part of their ongoing assault on Uyghur culture.
